# How to read gyroscope data with Arduino?

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I got one of these gyros, http://www.xheli.com/wag0diadpiin.html.

It has 6 pins 3,3. I'm afraid I might harm the device, so I wanted to ask here.

How should I connect it to Arduino? And what code should I use?

Comment: this website might be more appropriate for hardware: http://chiphacker.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have salvaged one of these off my old Walkera helicopter and want to do the same thing.  If no one has posted help here, I will try to sort this out and post another reply.

For what it's worth, the female 3 pin connector connects to a Walkera brushed speed controller (which in turn connects to 6-15 V battery power). The other three pins connected to the main circuit that had radio control and servo outputs.  This connector must have the pin to sample.  I am speculating, but I would guess that it would probably work best to connect it to `Int0` or `Int1` on the Arduino, instead of trying to poll it.

I would guess that two axis values might come from the chip, but the problem is knowing how the data encoded/muxed on the single output pin.

If I find out more, I will post an update. Good luck.